# Use logic formulas in columns

Tags: google-fusion-tables

in a map created with fusion table

I want to make sure that if the data is in a column, appear in the info windows, if there is no data may not be displayed the label of the column

it is possible ?

should be as follows:

**if (empty, no view label of column )also (fill in , view label end data)**

I apologize for my English

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [dynamic templates](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en&ref_topic=2575652).

The basic syntax would be:

```
{template .contents}
  <div>
    {if $data.value.columnName}
      <div><b>columnName:</b>{$data.value.columnName}</div>
    {/if}
  </div>
{/template}
```

Where `columnName` is the name of the column. Repeat the `{if/}`-condition for each column.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I am very inexperienced

you could get me some more practical example, or you can tell me other examples? the column in question must have special formatting?

thanks

Comment: This is a practical example, you only have to replace `columnName` with the name of the desired column and paste the code into the textbox for a custom infowindow-template.

Comment: Thank you very much 

ok I got it, I tried it and it works for that column but how do I let all the others? 

I copied the code in custom infowindow-template and replaced the name of the column in question, but in this way only appears that 

how do I add the rest?

Comment: ok ... I could, I left the problem of link 
I do because it appears as a clickable link?